# Qt: handling exceptions thrown from handlers of background threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, exception, qt4

I know that you need to reimplement the QApplication::notify() method to properly catch exceptions thrown from the main thread's event handlers.
But what about other threads? Say, I have an object with a slot, and this object lives in a QThread (with default run() method, which just calls exec()), i.e. the thread affinity of this object is the background QThread. So, where should I catch exceptions thrown from this object's slot?

IOW, how do I reimplement the notify() method of a background thread?

Comment: Possibly overload exec and put a try() { QThread::exec()} catch(...) { }

Comment: @drescherjm you mean that exceptions thrown from slots will "fly out of" the exec() method? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Yes I expected that to work. Sorry. I am out of ideas on this but subscribed.

Comment: @drescherjm : You can not overload QThread::exec,  this method is not virtual

Comment: Thanks. That explains why this did not work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your Custom Application with overriden notify method; the QThread you create uses this overriden method too (as the main thread) ***once it has started its own event loop***

It means in practice that if you connect any slot to the QThread::started signal; then this slot executes outside the event loop of thethread, thus not in the overriden notify method.

Here is a sample of code that helps to understand what happen:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <exception>

class ThrowingObject : public QObject
{
public:
    void doThrowInNotify()
    {
        qDebug() << "I am execution on thread id" << QThread::currentThreadId() << " and I am throwing";
        throw std::exception("KBOOOM");
    }

    void scheduleThrow()
    {
        QTimer* singleShot = new QTimer(this);
        singleShot->setSingleShot(true);

        connect(singleShot, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ThrowingObject::doThrow);

        singleShot->start();

        qDebug() << "I am execution on thread id" << QThread::currentThreadId() << " and I will throw in run";
    }

    void doThrow()
    {
        qDebug() << "I am execution on thread id" << QThread::currentThreadId() << " and I am throwing right now";

        //This exception is not catched, and definitly crash the process
        throw std::exception("KBOOOM");
    }

    void doThrowOutsideNotify()
    {
        //wait 5s for demo purpose, this slot is called by Object2, after Object1 throw in thread1 event loop
        QThread::sleep(5);
        qDebug() << "I am execution on thread id" << QThread::currentThreadId() << " and I am throwing right now";

        //This exception is not catched, and definitly crash the process
        throw std::exception("FATAL KBOOOM");
    }

};

class ApplicationWithExceptionCatchedInNotify : public QApplication
{
public:
    ApplicationWithExceptionCatchedInNotify(int argc, char *argv[]) :
        QApplication(argc,argv)
    {}

    bool notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent *e) override
    {
        try {
            return QApplication::notify(receiver, e);
        }
        catch(std::runtime_error e)
        {
            qDebug() << "std::runtime_error in thread : " << QThread::currentThreadId();
            qDebug() << e.what();
        }
        catch(std::exception e)
        {
            qDebug() << "std::exception in thread : " << QThread::currentThreadId();
            qDebug() << e.what();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            qDebug() << "exception thread : " << QThread::currentThreadId();
        }

        qDebug() << "catch in notify ";
        return false;
    }

};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ApplicationWithExceptionCatchedInNotify app(argc, argv);

qDebug() << "Main QThread id" << QThread::currentThreadId();

//Object o1 will throw in its event loop (in notify)
QThread thread1;
ThrowingObject o1;
o1.moveToThread(&thread1);

QObject::connect(&thread1, &QThread::started, &o1, &ThrowingObject::scheduleThrow);

thread1.start();

//Object o2 will throw before the event loop is installed
QThread thread2;
ThrowingObject o2;
o2.moveToThread(&thread2);
//Connect to started signal.
QObject::connect(&thread2, &QThread::started, &o2, &ThrowingObject::doThrowOutsideNotify);
thread2.start();

app.exec();
}
```

Running this code sample on windows , Qt 5.9 with Qt creator  gives for example :

Output :

```
Main QThread id 0x11e4
I am execution on thread id 0x180c  and I will throw in run
I am execution on thread id 0x180c  and I am throwing right now
std::exception in thread :  0x180c
KBOOOM
catch in notify 
I am execution on thread id 0x27b8  and I am throwing right now
```

and a Microsoft Visual Studio Runtime Library pop up crying that :

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Debug Error!

Program: ...ad-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\debug\DemoThread.exe

abort() has been called

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

If you put breakpoint; once can realize that :

Object o1 throws in QThread::exec methods, going down the callstack we can see we are in ApplicationWithExceptionCatchedInNotify::Notify

**1  ThrowingObject::doThrow                                                                                                       main.cpp                 35   0x7ff66615352b** 
2  QtPrivate::FunctorCall,QtPrivate::List<>,void,void (__cdecl ThrowingObject:: *)(void) __ptr64>::call qobjectdefs_impl.h       136  0x7ff66615358c 
3  QtPrivate::FunctionPointer::call,void>                     qobjectdefs_impl.h       170  0x7ff666152ce7 
4  QtPrivate::QSlotObject,void>::impl                          qobject_impl.h           121  0x7ff66615363e 
5  QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase::call                                                                                              qobject_impl.h           101  0x54a82428
6  QMetaObject::activate                                                                                                         qobject.cpp              3754 0x54a70ee0
7  QMetaObject::activate                                                                                                         qobject.cpp              3629 0x54a707a8
8  QTimer::timeout                                                                                                               moc_qtimer.cpp           202  0x54a8f739
9  QTimer::timerEvent                                                                                                            qtimer.cpp               257  0x54a8f79a
10 QObject::event                                                                                                                qobject.cpp              1228 0x54a72b73
11 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper                                                                                            qapplication.cpp         3722 0x53aeb8ee
12 QApplication::notify                                                                                                          qapplication.cpp         3094 0x53ae6323
13 ApplicationWithExceptionCatchedInNotify::notify                                                                               main.cpp                 60   0x7ff666158730 
14 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2                                                                                             qcoreapplication.cpp     1018 0x54a1b0c6
15 QCoreApplication::sendEvent                                                                                                   qcoreapplication.h       233  0x54a26062
16 QEventDispatcherWin32::event                                                                                                  qeventdispatcher_win.cpp 1041 0x54ad8cab
17 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper                                                                                            qapplication.cpp         3722 0x53aeb8ee
18 QApplication::notify                                                                                                          qapplication.cpp         3094 0x53ae6323
**19 ApplicationWithExceptionCatchedInNotify::notify                                                                               main.cpp                 60   0x7ff666158730** 
20 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2                                                                                             qcoreapplication.cpp     1018 0x54a1b0c6
21 QCoreApplication::sendEvent                                                                                                   qcoreapplication.h       233  0x54a26062
22 QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents                                                                                     qcoreapplication.cpp     1678 0x54a1c982
23 QEventDispatcherWin32::sendPostedEvents                                                                                       qeventdispatcher_win.cpp 1064 0x54ad8e6a
24 qt_internal_proc                                                                                                              qeventdispatcher_win.cpp 237  0x54ad6b47
25 CallWindowProcW                                                                                                               USER32                        0x7ffba1571c24 
26 DispatchMessageW                                                                                                              USER32                        0x7ffba157156c 
27 QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents                                                                                          qeventdispatcher_win.cpp 628  0x54ad755b
28 QEventLoop::processEvents                                                                                                     qeventloop.cpp           135  0x54a15498
29 QEventLoop::exec                                                                                                              qeventloop.cpp           212  0x54a156de
30 QThread::exec                                                                                                                 qthread.cpp              515  0x5465028f
31 QThread::run                                                                                                                  qthread.cpp              583  0x546501c3
32 QThreadPrivate::start                                                                                                         qthread_win.cpp          380  0x5465caed
33 BaseThreadInitThunk                                                                                                           KERNEL32                      0x7ffb9f5b8364 
34 RtlUserThreadStart                                                                                                            ntdll                         0x7ffba1bb7091

Object o2 throws in QThread::start methods; outside of the thread2 event loop

**1  ThrowingObject::doThrowOutsideNotify                                                                                          main.cpp           45   0x7ff666152ba6** 
2  QtPrivate::FunctorCall,QtPrivate::List<>,void,void (__cdecl ThrowingObject:: *)(void) __ptr64>::call qobjectdefs_impl.h 136  0x7ff66615358c 
3  QtPrivate::FunctionPointer::call,void>                     qobjectdefs_impl.h 170  0x7ff666152ce7 
4  QtPrivate::QSlotObject,void>::impl                          qobject_impl.h     121  0x7ff66615363e 
5  QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase::call                                                                                              qobject_impl.h     101  0x54a82428
6  QMetaObject::activate                                                                                                         qobject.cpp        3754 0x54a70ee0
7  QMetaObject::activate                                                                                                         qobject.cpp        3629 0x54a707a8
**8  QThread::started                                                                                                              moc_qthread.cpp    160  0x54650149**
9  QThreadPrivate::start                                                                                                         qthread_win.cpp    377  0x5465cad6
10 BaseThreadInitThunk                                                                                                           KERNEL32                0x7ffb9f5b8364 
11 RtlUserThreadStart                                                                                                            ntdll                   0x7ffba1bb7091

Answer (score 1):

Since certain version of Qt5, the `QCoreApplication::notify` manual says:

> this function is called for all events sent to any object in any
> thread.

So this means that the correct answer to my original question was "just do what you were doing all along".

Funnily, just as I discovered this, this newly discovered knowledge instantly became outdated by this phrase from *the very same manual*:

> This function will not be called for objects that live outside the
> main thread in Qt 6. Applications that need that functionality should
> find other solutions for their event inspection needs in the meantime.
> The change may be extended to the main thread, causing this function
> to be deprecated.

LOL. I have not migrated to Qt6 yet so I have no idea what's the situation there, but when I do, I might just re-open this exact question.